# Keyframing Constraints - Is it possible?

Tags: constraints

So, this is all hypothetical. This isn't really anything I am trying to do at the moment, but what I want to know is how to keyframe constraints. Example: Say I have an item that - at some point in the animation - needs to be picked up by a character. (e.g. the item could be a sandwich.) Is there any way to initialize a 'child-of' constraint type and have it become inactive or dormant at points in the animation? If you had a character with a constrained item object, then it would seem reasonable for him to have a need within your plot to put the item down and not have that item drag along behind him every time he moved his hand like a puppet tied to his finger with an invisible thread.

Thanks!

Comment: Does [**this**](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Constraints/Relationship/Child_Of) help?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Wait, is it the influence parameter affecting that? If I keyframe influence to 0 will that parenting relationship be lost? (Temporarily, I mean.)

Comment: That is what I gathered form it. Give it a try and see how it works!

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Thank you! I can't actually try it right this minute, but I can assume it will work! :)

Comment: I will see if I can rig something up and test it real quick, I'll let you know what I come up with!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by animating the *Influence* value *(hover over it and press <kbd>I</kbd>)*. This tells Blender how much the constraint will affect the object.

[image]

Comment: To add a keyframe: hover over the influence slider and press **I**.

Comment: Right-clicking the influence slider shows more keyframe options, including options to add a driver.