# Temporary animating physical objects

Tags: animation, physics, constraints

I am looking for a way to control physical objects, preferably with an armature, where the bones have variable influence from 100% making objects follow the bones and 0% where physical objects unaffected by the armature.

I have tried to enable **Animated** option in the rigid body settings, but this does not give an option for a variable influence and the objects jump back to the original position when **Animated** option is enabled.

[image]

Same problem occurs while using object constraints, when the influence changed to 0, the object is displaced to the original location and not following the inertia.

I also have tried applying force to the bone, but then it is not possible to clamp the object/s to the bone/s location.

Comment: Do you need to animate the bone to meet the physical object? When the animated checkbox is ticked the object comes under the influence of the armature again so it goes to wherever the bone is.

Comment: @d8sconz I need a gradual influence between the bone and the physics, lets say 1 is 100% following the bone and 0 is 100% physical object, and in between the object behaves like its connected with a rubber string.

Answer (score 1):

Look into constraints, they have an influence property that can be animated like this: [Keyframing Constraints - Is it possible?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23081/keyframing-constraints-is-it-possible)

For example you could animate an empty object, and constrain your body with "Copy Location" constraint to it.

Comment: I have tried that already, the problem with object constraints is that when the influence is changed to 0 the object falls down like it was in the original position and not following the inertia.

Comment: I am not sure that I fully understand what you want, but if you want inertia, you can achieve it by adding more keyframes, like here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5100/how-can-i-add-motion-to-a-rigid-body

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to make possible to morph gradually between a state where the objects have a physical behavior to a state where the objects clamp to position and rotation of a bones, or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can mute all the selected channels (<kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd>) in graph editor, then you can disable the armature modifier in viewport. This should make the animation start then stop.

If you want truly variable animation, consider using the [Blender Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as 50% physics.  Or 33%, or 99%.  There is 0% and there is 100%.

You *can* smoothly interpolate between the orientation given by physics and the orientation given by armature.

[image]

Here I have an object linked to an armature, where I can make a bone copy the transformation of a falling rigid body cube more or less closely.

But from the sounds of it, that's not what you want, because when I reduce the influence, the cube will bound back up.

Once you disable physics, you no longer have memory of what has happened-- there is no inertia without physics.

But you can animate physics parameters.  You can animate gravity, for example-- a rigid body without gravity will have inertia, but it will not fall.

You can also create rigid body constraints, with parameters that you can animate.

[image]

Here I've got my main cube linked by a rigid body constraint to an animated rigid body (which probably should be set to not render), which is parented to a bone.  Because the constraint's settings are so strong, my rigid body basically follows the bone, and I can animate or drive the strength of those constraints.

During periods of the animation when the constraints are weak, I can move the controller close to the cube without affecting it.  If I don't, making the constraints strong again will just suck the cube back to the bone.